# DataTable error when using the search field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a problem here already spent a few hours and I can not solve, I'm using **DataTable** as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("Entrou na função"); 
            var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                "destroy": true,                    
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"phpmysql_serverside.php", // json datasource
                    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                    error: function(){  // error handling
                        $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                        $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">Sem registros</th></tr></tbody>');
                        $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                    }
                }
            } );
        } );
```

Here usually works the search field, but when I put this script below to translate the search for work, since fucei at all and do not think the problem.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#employee-grid').dataTable( {
        //paging: false,    // desativa paginação 
        //ordering: false, //desativa ordenação no cabeçalho
        //searching: false, // desativa a pesquisa no topo
        "bDestroy": true,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        iDisplayLength: 25,    
        iDisplayStart: 3,

        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ total registros)",

        }, 


        sPagination: "full_numbers",
        bStateSave: true,
        sScorollX: "300px", 
        sScrollY: "550px",
        bScrollInfinite:true, //this property disables pagination
        oSearch: { "sSearch": "Digite Aqui...", "bRegex": false, "bSmart": false }
});
});
</script>
```

PS: My **PHP** page is running normally, because only problem when I use the second script.

Comment: The first example uses v1.10 syntax, and the second example uses v.1.9 syntax.  Is that the issue?